# Error starting "XAMPP" stack: cannot calculate MAC address: signal killed

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I recently installed XAMPP-VM on my Mac. I am encountering a problem whenever I click Start in the General tab. Log tab shows that...

> INFO: Starting "XAMPP" stack
>
> ERROR: Error starting "XAMPP" stack: cannot calculate MAC address: signal: killed

As an individual who is not knowledgeable of such error, could someone explain what this error means and how to fix it? [image: General Tab][image: Error encounter][image: Log Tab]

Answer (score 76):

I had the same problem and fixed it.

You have to close xampp, then type on your terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/.bitnami/stackman
```

And open xampp again.

Hope it works for you :) .

Comment: No.  It didn't work for me neither.  I use a freshly download XAMPP today for installation.  I am on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and the machine is MB Pro Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015.

Comment: @hb5fa Same here.

Comment: it worked for me, however, all my "htdocs" data are gone (because new xampp was installed)

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me. Can you quickly explain what that command does?

Comment: This solution works by removing existing project files. Is there a better and safer way to go about this?

Comment: i think its all data from previous version of XAMPP. To use a newer version, the old stackman files have to be removed before giving root access.

Comment: This also work for me. There is a previous install before cause the issue.

Comment: It worked for me. saved a lot of my time

Comment: Any idea how to get old files? I have updated macOS Monterey and gone all the data.

Comment: I am getting this error "cannot calculate MAC address: hv_vm_create unknown error -85377017"

Comment: Thank you, this command solve my problem:)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have these requirements to use XAMPP-VM platform:

- OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite or later
- a 2010 or later Mac (i.e. a CPU that supports EPT)

UPDATE:

Unfortunately you can not use XAMPP-VM if you don't have this requirements but you can use the regular OS X native installer available at https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: Hello, I'm using a mid 2014 model of Macbook Pro. In addition, current system version is macOS 10.12.6 which is Sierra.

Comment: Can you execute the command:
     "sysctl kern.hv_support"
If the output is: 
    "kern.hv_support: 0"
is because is not supported

Comment: Output is "kern.hv_support: 1"

Comment: Wow that's weird, I wasn't expecting that but is a good notice for you,. Did you tried to set the MAC address manually? If not, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Did you had any old version of apache? I'm with out more ideas, if you find out the solution please post it.
This can be good for you: https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/339

Comment: No, had my ssd upgraded. Just installing all dev tools that I use. Yes, will post the solution here when I figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @nkpg do you found the solution yet ?

Comment: @DarrenLau nope, sorry.

Comment: @nkpg I using non vm version xampp installer it’s working fine for me, give it a try ?

Comment: @DarrenLau Yes, that's what I did. I just wanted to try that one. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

For people using Apple silicon chips, using installer.dmg instead of vm.dmg works.

For example, I used the following link for version 8.4.1:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Mac%20OS%20X/8.1.4/xampp-osx-8.1.4-0-installer.dmg/download

Comment: Also for people not familiar with MAC, you are a saviour!

Answer (score 1):

Hitting the same error. However, I pressed start after a while it works. lol...

[image]

Running Mac OS 10.12.6 (16G29) and XAMPP 7.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Anyone is still facing the issue of macOS Big Sur. Below I have attached few commands please follow the same.

**Important: Make sure to take the backup of the working projects manually.**

**#create a backup of your contents inside htdocs**

> cp -rp ~/.bitnami ~/.bitnami.back

**#note: this command enters tmp folder if you are in Users/ directory**

> cd ../../tmp

**#installs hyper kit**

> curl -LJO "https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/hyperkit/hyperkit-testing-20210430"

**#Check the hash**

> md5 /tmp/hyperkit-testing-20210430

**#move the hyper kit**

> mv /tmp/hyperkit-testing-20210430 ~/.bitnami/stackman/helpers/hyperkit

**#give permission for hyper kit**

> chmod +x ~/.bitnami/stackman/helpers/hyperkit

Also I have attached the video link: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfQHNQTj28c](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfQHNQTj28c&ab_channel=AnupDhal)

Comment: why `cd ../../tmp`, when you can just `cd /tmp`???

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. That also we can try.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for Big Sur (probably works up to, but not including, Ventura) if you are trying to get the contents of your VM working as well.

1. Rename the current `.bitnami/stackman` folder to something else like `stackman_old`
2. Open up the Bitnami VM and it should rebuild the `stackman` folder and reassign a new localhost IP address.
3. Make sure that VM works by starting it up and checking it's all green
4. If good, quit the VM again
5. Move the `stackman_old/machines/xampp/ssh` folder into the same place into the new `stackman` folder.
6. Move the `stackman_old/machines/xampp/vm` folder into the same place into the new `stackman` folder.

After doing these two folder replacements, open up the VM again and it should start up fine, just will have the new IP address so if you are referencing that ip in your `etc/hosts` file, you'll have to update those so it's pointing to the right place.

Hopefully this helps someone!